# What is the actual use of "signed" keyword?

Tags: c++

I know that unsigned integers are only positive numbers (and 0), and can have double the value compared to a normal int. Are there any difference between

```
int variable = 12;
```

And:

```
signed int variable = 12;
```

When and why should you use the signed keyword?

Comment: Almost never. It's implied. One possible exception is `signed char`; the standard doesn't specify whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned, so if for some reason you specifically want a signed char, you have to say that explicitly.

Comment: I use it to show that the number is explicitly signed, more of a reminder to the reader.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Even more, `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are *three* distinct types. For all other integral types, `X` and `signed X` are the same.

Comment: If you write `signed` then you can actually drop the `int`. I have no idea why one would want to do that, but it does make an occasion where the presence of `signed` is not superfluous.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There is only one instance where you might want to use the `signed` keyword. `signed char` is always a different type from "plain" `char`, which may be a signed or an unsigned type depending on the implementation.

C++14 3.9.1/1 says:

> It is implementation-defined whether a `char` object can hold negative values. Characters can be explicitly declared `unsigned` or `signed`. Plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types [...]

In other contexts `signed` is redundant.

---

Prior to C++14, (and in C), there was a second instance: bit-fields. It was implementation-defined whether, for example, `int x:2;` (in the declaration of a class) is the same as `unsigned int x:2;` or the same as `signed int x:2`.

C++11 9.6/3 said:

> It is implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long` bit-field is signed or unsigned.

However, since C++14 this has been changed so that `int x:2;` always means `signed int`. [Link to discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723631/signed-bit-field-in-c14)

Comment: and note that historically, PowerPC-based compilers have treated `char` as `unsigned` by default, whereas x86 and ARM have treated it as `signed`.

Comment: @fluffy: If `char` is 8 bits and the source character set is EBCDIC, then `char` must, in the absence of a `signed` or `unsigned` keyword, be unsigned, since EBCDIC represents the digits 0-9 with codes 0xF0 through 0xF9 and digits (as well as letters and any punctuation defined in the C standard) must be represented by positive `char` values.  BTW, on machines where `char` and `int` are the same size, `char` could not be equivalent to `unsigned char`, since `int` must be able to hold all the values of `char`, but `unsigned char` can't have padding.

Comment: Why latest drawn c++11, such as N3690/N3797, doesn't have the statement: "It is implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) char, short, int, long, or long long bit-field is signed or unsigned". Is it changed?

Comment: @pezy: Only because I don't yet have a copy of the latest standard although these sections haven't changed to my knowledge.

Comment: @CharlesBailey The second has changed. Given `template <typename T> struct S;`, `S<int>` and `S<signed int>` are the same type. They must remain the same type even if `S` ends up defined as `template <typename T> struct S { T bitfield : 4; };`, so the implementation-defined signedness of bit-fields was unworkable. There was a proposal to limit the implementation-defined signedness to bit-fields with a non-dependent type, but that never made it into the standard. In the end, the permission to treat such bit-fields as unsigned was simply removed. See CWG issues 675 and 739.

Comment: @hvd: I wish the C standard would introduce distinct "whole quantity" and "algebraic ring" types.  The behavior when combining signed/unsigned types of the same size is appropriate when the types are used as algebraic rings (which they often are) but promotion of unsigned types to larger signed types only makes sense when the types are used to represent whole quantities.  If bitfields (and other things) could be defined as holding whole quantities, then it would be be possible to say that an operation between such a bitfield and a signed value would yield a signed number large enough...

Comment: ...to hold all whole-number values represented by the bitfield [so on a system with 32-bit `int`, a whole-quantity bitfield of size 31 or less would yield an `int` rvalue; those 32 bits or more would yield a `long` rvalue].  I don't think the fact that the bitfield can't hold negative numbers should cause difficulties with its rvalue being interpreted as signed.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of `int`, there's no difference. It only makes a difference with `char`, because

1. it is not defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned, and
2. `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types anyway.

So you should use `signed` if you need a `signed char` (which is probably rarely). Other than that,  I can't think of a reason.

Comment: good point about char, and to be honest, compilers (notably devstudio) let you specify what the default is for char

Comment: @hvanbrug: I don't think that's "notable". Notable is that GCC has such an option.

Comment: barring compiler snobbery I just mentioned devstudio because I was certain that it did. I was not certain about gcc so I did not mention it. Also, GCC is not MORE notable than dev studio. When you consider that windows still has the largest install base by far in the world it is easy to see that dev studio, and as such visual C++ has a great many users (as does GCC). That said, maybe the word "including" would have brought my point across better than "notably".

Comment: @hvanbrug: You mean Visual Studio?  (That's an IDE, not a compiler.  And its C++ compiler hasn't particularly cared about standards until relatively recently.)  Or Anjuta DevStudio (another IDE)?  If you actually mean a compiler named "devstudio", then i'm afraid it's not at all notable, because basically no one's heard of it.

Comment: @cHao: I am in the bad habit of calling VC++ DevStudio. +1 for catching me on the naming habit. I do understand that Visual Studio (used to be called Dev Studio a long time ago) is the IDE, but my bad habit stems from me only using it for VC++. You are correct that VC++ is not known for following standards, but that's not really the issue. I was just pointing out that that particular compiler (which is widely used) does allow you to specify whether chars default to signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 4):

`signed` is the default integer type. So no, there is no difference in the example you gave. There is a difference only in the case of `char`.

Source: [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference  between the two where int's are concerned. You might include the word signed for formatting if you are also declaring unsigned int's so that they are easier to line up and make readable, but for all intents and purposes you don't need to use the signed keyword.

Comment: "You might include ... for formatting" is a really poor reason to add something to code. First of all, people should strive to make their code simple, and avoiding unnecessary clutter makes code simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion @cmaster. In my opinion formatting is a very important topic. In my 30+ years of programming I have seen more mistakes made because the developer could not read the code and therefore misunderstood the meaning. It should always be on a programmers mind to make sure their code is readable because you may not be the only one looking at it, and for that matter, in a few years you may not recognize your own code either.

Comment: @cmaster I think you're cherry picking words for a reason to downvote. Read his answer as a whole again.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek, hvanbrug: I did't downvote. It's not exactly a wrong answer, so it doesn't deserve a downvote imho. I just commented that formatting is a really poor reason for adding anything to a program. Yes, formatting is important, but formatting should be restricted to whitespace. But more important than formatting is a good, clear, and simple structure of the code that can be paraded by proper formatting. I have never added, and will (hopefully) never add `signed` to my code for formatting purposes.

Comment: I could understand using it if you're messing with a bunch of unsigned variables, and then for some reason have a signed one.  It makes clearer that you *meant* for it to be signed, and didn't just forget the `unsigned` there.  But that's more than just formatting; code prettiness isn't really even a factor.