# Signed bit field in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, bit-fields

I believe that until C++14 a bit field of a struct declared as `int` was still interpreted as either `signed` or `unsigned`, the interpretation being implementation defined. Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field.

Is this still the case in C++14? I.e., is the code below guaranteed to work as inteded?

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int f:3;
};

int main() 
{
    X x;
    x.f = -2; // is this going to be indeed signed? It seems so.
    std::cout << x.f << std::endl; // displays -2
}
```

Comment: [CWG 739](http://wg21.link/CWG739). It's a DR.

Comment: @T.C. How come you know all these DRs -- o.O (also, please consider posting an answer. This is helpful)

Comment: @sehe I'm also asking myself the same thing :)

Comment: @sehe Nothing easier than [that](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/). There is close to no skill required to find DRs corresponding to a section (or topic) of the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to C++11 standard *§9.6/p3 Bit-fields [class.bit]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> A bit-field shall not be a static member. A bit-field shall have
> integral or enumeration type (3.9.1). **It is implementation-defined
> whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) `char`, `short`,
> `int`, `long`, or `long long` bit-field is signed or unsigned.** A `bool` value
> can successfully be stored in a bit-field of any nonzero size. The
> address-of operator & shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there
> are no pointers to bitfields. A non-const reference shall not be bound
> to a bit-field (8.5.3). [ Note: If the initializer for a reference of
> type const T& is an lvalue that refers to a bit-field, the reference
> is bound to a temporary initialized to hold the value of the
> bit-field; the reference is not bound to the bit-field directly. See
> 8.5.3. —end note ]

So you're correct for the first part. Indeed until C++14 a bit field of a struct not specifically declared as `signed` was still interpreted as either `signed` or `unsigned`, the interpretation being implementation defined.

As already mentioned in this comments by [@T.C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c). Defect reports referring to the issue were made [DR739](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#739), [DR675](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#675). Resulting in the following resolutions in C++14 standard:

The wording "It is implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long` bit-field is signed or unsigned.",  was removed, and the C++14 wording now is:

> A bit-field shall not be a static member. A bit-field shall have
> integral or enumeration type (3.9.1). A bool value can successfully be
> stored in a bit-field of any nonzero size. The address-of operator &
> shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there are no pointers to
> bit-fields. A non-const reference shall not be bound to a bit-field
> (8.5.3). [ Note: If the initializer for a reference of type const T&
> is an lvalue that refers to a bit-field, the reference is bound to a
> temporary initialized to hold the value of the bit-field; the
> reference is not bound to the bit-field directly. See 8.5.3. —end note
> ]

Also in *§C.1.8 Clause 9: classes [diff.class]* the following section was added:

> 9.6
>
> **Change:** Bit-fields of type plain int are signed.
>
> **Rationale:** Leaving the choice of signedness to implementations could lead to inconsistent definitions of
> template specializations. For consistency, the implementation freedom was eliminated for non-dependent
> types, too.
>
> **Effect on original feature:** The choice is implementation-defined in C, but not so in C++.
>
> **Difficulty of converting:** Syntactic transformation.
>
> **How widely used:** Seldom.

Consequently, in C++14 **bit-fields of type plain `int` are signed** and the code posted is guaranteed to work as intended.

Comment: The green text in CW 739 says that the change only applies to dependent types. Was that text not actually adopted?

Comment: @M.M There are two PRs for that DR. The February 2012 one is the one applied.